# Class template for cache aligned memory usage in C++

Tags: c++, templates, memory-management

(to provide the information you need to understand my question is a lot, however it is already compressed)

i try to implement a class template to allocate and access data cache aligned. This works very good, however trying to implement support for arrays is a problem.

Semantically the code shall provide this mapping in memory for a single element like this:

```
cache_aligned<element_type>* my_el = 
          new(cache_line_size) cache_aligned<element_type>();
| element | buffer |
```

the access (so far) looks like this:

```
*my_el; // returns cache_aligned<element_type>
**my_el; //returns element_type
*my_el->member_of_element();
```

HOWEVER for an array, i'd like to have this:

```
 cache_aligned<element_type>* my_el_array = 
         new(cache_line_size)  cache_aligned<element_type()[N];
 | element 0 | buffer | element 1 | buffer | ... | element (N-1) | buffer |
```

So far i have the following code

```
template <typename T>
class cache_aligned {
    private:
        T instance;
    public:
        cache_aligned()
        {}
        cache_aligned(const T& other)
        :instance(other.instance)
        {}
        static void* operator new (size_t size, uint c_line_size) {
             return c_a_malloc(size, c_line_size);
        }
        static void* operator new[] (size_t size, uint c_line_size) {
             int num_el = (size - sizeof(cache_aligned<T>*) 
                              / sizeof(cache_aligned<T>);
             return c_a_array(sizeof(cache_aligned<T>), num_el, c_line_size);
        }
        static void operator delete (void* ptr) {
             free_c_a(ptr);
        }
        T* operator-> () {
             return &instance;
        }
        T& operator * () {
             return instance;
        }
};
```

the functions cache_aligned_malloc

```
void* c_a_array(uint size, ulong num_el, uint c_line_size) {
    void* mem = malloc((size + c_line_size) * num_el + sizeof(void*));
    void** ptr = (void**)((long)mem + sizeof(void*));
    ptr[-1] = mem;
    return ptr;
}

void free_c_a(void ptr) {
    free(((void**)ptr)[-1]);
}
```

The problem is here, the access to the data should work like this:

```
my_el_array[i]; // returns cache_aligned<element_type>
*(my_el_array[i]); // returns element_type
my_el_array[i]->member_of_element();
```

My ideas to solve it, are:

(1) something similar to this, to overload sizeof operator:

```
static size_t operator sizeof () {
   return sizeof(cache_aligned<T>) + c_line_size;
}
```

--> not possible since overloading sizeof operator is illegal

(2) something like this, to overload the operator [] for the pointer type:

```
static T& operator [] (uint index, cache_aligned<T>* ptr) {
    return ptr + ((sizeof(cache_aligned<T>) + c_line_size) * index);
}
```

--> not possible in C++, anyway

(3) totally trivial solution

```
template <typename T> cache_aligned {
    private:
          T instance;
          bool buffer[CACHE_LINE_SIZE]; 
          // CACHE_LINE_SIZE defined as macro
    public:
          // trivial operators and methods ;)
};
```

--> i don't know whether this is reliable, actually i'm using gcc-4.5.1 in linux ...

(4) Replacing T instance; by T* instance_ptr; in the class template and using the operator [] to calculate the position of the element, like this:

| pointer-to-instance | ----> | element 0 | buffer | ... | element (N-1) | buffer |

this is not the intended semantic, since the instance of the class template becomes the bottleneck when calculating the address of the elements.

Thanks for reading! I dont' know how to shorten the problem. It would be great, if you can help! Any work around would help a lot.

I know alignment is an extension in C++0x. However, in gcc it is not available yet.

Greetz, sema

Comment: do you need a portable (that is to non gcc compilers) solution? If not (and you can get away with defining the cache line size as macro/template parameter), you could try using __attribute__((aligned(..))) until c++0x alignas becomes availible for you.

Comment: thanks a lot! this does not solve the original problem, but it is a work around i will consider. maybe it's sufficient to solve the most important problems =)

Comment: your welcome. For the record I think other then using compiler specific extensions your (3) is probably the way to go (except you might want to use CACHE_LINE_SIZE-sizeof(T) for your buffer (not exactly, since sizeof(T) might be > CACHE_LINE_SIZE, but you get the point, and I think char buffer[...] would probably be a better type since I think that bool isn't specified clearly enough for this case (as in might be vary in size for different implementations).

Comment: thanks again for your reply, is it reliable that declaring the class template like in solution (3) is allocated in memory this way: | element | buffer | and not sometimes | buffer | element | ? in the latter it could be this way | buffer | element 0 | element 1 | buffer| and as a result element 0 and element 1 share a cache line. further more when accessing an instance of cache_aligned<element_type> is all memory of the instance loaded in the cache? this would also result in false sharing =) btw. i would give you the answer check mark, but you replied only via comment =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When c_line_size is compile time integral constant then of course better pad the cache_aligned with char array depending on sizeof T.

You can also check if 2 T-s fit onto one cache line and lower the alignment requirement accordingly.

Do not expect miracles from such an optimization. I think 2 times better performance for some algorithms is the ceiling that you can squeeze out from avoiding cache line splits.

Comment: Actually it can make much more of a difference then factor 2 for multithreaded applications, exspecially if sizeof(T) << cache_line_size (putting more then one T in a cache line would not be a good idea if optimizing for this). This is simply because different threads working on objects sharing a cacheline can easily make the cache coherency protocol a bottleneck (of course depending how fast the connection between those caches is and if the machine is cache coherent or not). For other situations I would expect a lot less then a factor of 2 (might even be <0 due to reduced data locality).

Comment: Yes, that is what i said one should profile and not expect wonders since it depends on platform and what he does with T. If he uses all T for something then on Intel Core 2 the penalty when data comes from different cache lines instead of one is quite large ... unlike on other processors. On the other hand if the algorithm involves different cores writing to adjacent array elements then it might be good idea to think over that algorithm too.